# How to access "this" component in Vue 3 @click event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, ref

I'm using `Vue 3` and in a v-for loop, I'm creating multiple button elements. The buttons are being made in another component named `wb-button`. So I call `wb-button` in every v-for loop.

I add @click event listener to the `wb-button` that calls a method inside the current component, simple:

```
<div v-for="(item,key) in items" :key="key">
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    <wb-button @click="deleteItem(item)">
        Delete item!
    </wb-button>
</div>
```

This works how I want, the problem starts when I want to pass the `wb-button` just like a ref to the `deleteItem` method. The purpose is to make changes to another ref inside the `wb-button`. So what I basically want to do is this:

```
export default{
    name: 'listComponent',
    methods:{
        async deleteItem(item,wbButtonRef){
            // The next line is what I want to do
            wbButtonRef.$refs.btnElement.putInLoadingStatus()
            // do the delete item action
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can create a ref on each `wb-button` and pass an ID or something to the method, but I don't think it is the cleanest way to do it.

If there was something to just pass the `wb-button` element as the method parameter it would be great. Something like this:

```
    <!-- I want to know if there is something I can put in 
the second argument of the 'wb-button' @click event -->

    <wb-button @click="deleteItem(item, /* what to put here?*/)">

    <!-- "this","$this","$event.target" etc ... -->
```

I have tried $event.target but it returns the root element of `wb-button`, what I need is the `wb-button` itself just like a $ref.

Comment: Do you just want to change the text from "Delete item!" to "Please wait"?

Comment: @MrFabio_25 That's not all I want to do, I actually want to call a method inside the `wb-button` component. So having the reference instead of the DOM element is necessary.

Comment: @MrFabio_25 I have edited my question regarding the misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok got it. Maybe you could handle the click event inside you wb-button component and emit an event from your wb-button. Then you could listen to that event in your parent component if you want to execute some additional logic

Comment: @MrFabio_25 True, I had that option in mind too. But I just wanted to make it work in the parent component as the child component is being used in other places too. But eventually, I will do this if I can not find any other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. And since this logic is relevant only for the button component itself, it's best to keep this logic within it. Adding a prop and render something based on that, like you suggested yourself in the comments, is a good way to go about it.

Comment: Uh, it was a misunderstanding. The `.innerHTML` was just an example (a bad one). What I really want to do is calling a method on a grand-child $ref. I have fixed the question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wonder though, what's the reason you want to call a method within the child component? You can't do this, but maybe I can provide an alternative if I know what you're exactly trying to achieve. I'm guessing that `putInLoadingStatus` does something else than trying to delete the component itself.

Comment: As the name of the method implies (putInLoadingStatus) it sets `this.isLoading=true` so the button content will change accordingly - adds a spinner, shows loading status, and makes the button disabled.

Comment: It actually just shows the loading status until we do an Ajax call, and then delete the item. (That's why I defined an async function)

Comment: So why call it from the parent component? You can just set the @click listener on the top-level div in the button component itself, right?

Comment: Because it is being used in other components, I might want to call different functions according to the place it is being called. But that is actually a good point, I can add a "loading-type" prop to the component to make it work.

Comment: That's the way I always do these things ;). I'll edit my answer to match the updated question, btw

Comment: I will accept your answer, but I have done some edits to make sure it contains all the possibilities. Thanks

Comment: @MahyarKhanbabai That's fine, but you should add an answer of your own with that text, so that it's clear that that is your own resolution. I'll keep it open for the moment, so you can still copy-paste your suggested edit.

Comment: I'd also like to note that the second option still refers to calling the child method, which would not work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have added another answer, thanks for keeping it open, you can close it now.

Answer (score 0):

**Considering Other Options**

Although I used @paddotk 's answer, 'the props way' to solve my problem, I'm just adding this answer so anyone who reads this question afterward would have a complete answer.

As far as I have found out, there are two more ways of doing this:

1- As @MrFabio_25 mentioned in the comments, I can create a custom event on the child component and $emit with 'this' as a parameter, so I can handle that in the parent:

```
// wbButton.vue file

<inside-wb-component ref="btnElement" @click="handleClick">
     <button>
          <slot></slot>
     </button>
</inside-wb-component>  

//and in the script tag
//...
methods:{
     handleClick(){
          this.$emit('buttonClick',this)
     }
}
//...
```

And simply in the parent component:

```
<wb-button @buttonClick="handleButtonClick">
     A text here
</wb-button>
// in the script tag
methods:{
     handleButtonClick(elem){
          elem.$refs.btnElement.putInLoadingStatus()
     }
}
```

2- The second way to do so, without the child component being involved, is to use an array of refs, as explained here:
[Vue 3 Documentation - refs inside v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for)

```
<div v-for="(item,key) in items" :key="key">
     <wb-button ref="wbButtonRefs" @click="handleButtonClick(item,key)">
          A text here
     </wb-button>
</div>
// and in scripts tag
//...
methods:{
     handleButtonClick(item,index){
          const buttonRef=this.$refs.wbButtonRefs[index]
          // Now do whatever with buttonRef
          buttonRef.$refs.btnElement.putInLoadingStatus()
     }
}
//...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<template>
   <button @click="test($event)">Test</button>
</template>



methods:{
     test(e){
          const comp = e.target.__vueParentComponent
          const props = comp.props
     }
}
```

Comment: Please explain this solution as part of your answer. Code snippets are not very helpful for people who are looking to weigh up multiple solutions. Remember we are trying to inform people, not just solve problems.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.